# Hover on button producing error inside Django

Tags: django, django-models

my_path is a field in models.py where

```
my_path = models.FilePathField('some/path/)
```

in my template I have the following where on hover on the button will play an audio.

```
<audio id='mySound' controls="controls" preload="auto">
    <source src={{ my_path }} type="audio/ogg">
</audio>

<button style="font-size:30px"><i id='someIcon' class="fa fa-play">   </i></button>
```

I verified that my_path points to an audio file (/static/audio/someaudio.ogg), in fact the same path works outside of Django. But in Django

I am having this error,

GET 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_name/some_url/static/audio/someaudio.ogg      [HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 22ms]

I tried to hard code the path but same error?

Comment: Have you done `{% load static %}` in your template then tried to access it with a static url?

Comment: I tried <source src="{% static "{{my_path}}" %}"></source>, but I don't think I cant nest {{}} inside {%%}.

Comment: `FilePathField` isn't intended for use with public static files. The `path` that you supply is an *absolute* filesystem path (which could be anywhere in your system, not just inside the static root), and this is what will get rendered in the template. If you want to use the field for static files then you need to generate your own public URL, e.g., with a template tag or a method on the model.

Comment: It's working now, all comments helped. Thanks.